# PHP I want load language file but show errror

Tags: php

call to function $this->language(); show error Notice: Undefined variable: malik in D:\Malik\XAMPP\htdocs\projects\mvc\app\controllers\home.php on line 7
when i try this $malik = $this->language(); no langauge code work
please see code in bitbucket and help me link https://bitbucket.org/malikumer/mvc/src
Please solve my problem

Comment: You should read [ask]

Comment: Hay pvg if you know please help ke I am unable to write long paragraph in English because I am not notice in English

Comment: The problem is not your English, it's that you just linked to your code. This isn't a place where you come to ask for help without trying to help yourself first. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the `$malik` variable which is in `MVC/app/local/malik.en.php` you should return it from the `language()` method or set it as constant, as it's a *local scope variable* and will then only be available within the `language()` method.

```
public function language()
{
    require_once "../app/local/malik.en.php";
    if (is_array($malik)) {
        return $malik;
    }

    return [];
}
```

Then within your controller change your code to:

```
<?php               
class Home extends Controller
{
    public function index($name='')
    { 
        $malik = $this->language();

        $this->view($this->theme(), "home/index" , $malik);
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could set the language into class scope:

```
public function language()
{
    require_once "../app/local/malik.en.php";
    if (is_array($malik)) {
        $this->malik = $malik;
    }

    $this->malik = [];
}
```

Then it will be available without needing to assign it to a variable within your controller method.

```
<?php               
class Home extends Controller
{
    public function index($name='')
    { 
        $this->language();

        $this->view($this->theme(), "home/index" , $this->malik);
    }

}
```

Also, I'm guessing `$malik` is your name, would it not better be suited as `$language`?

Comment: Sir in controller.php file I have public function language()
 {
  require_once "../app/local/malik.en.php";
 }. So I call in home controller the variable come form language not but not work

Comment: The data is empty aray that I pass during function creation see controller.php

Comment: yeah i can see `public function view($theme,$view, $data = [] )` but that's not the issue, the issue is you have not set the variable, `$malik` anywhere within the scope of the method, so leave it out like `$this->view($this->theme(),"home/index" );` are you sure it should not be `$name`?

Comment: Sir I load file Malik.en.php is not work that's issue why if I jut include file in home controller It's wok if I create function and then call to function It's not work

Comment: public function language() { require_once "../app/local/malik.en.php"; }

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I've made my edit which should be your fix.

Comment: np, another way would be to set it to `$this->malik` from within the `language()` method then it will be available to child controllers.

Comment: Ok sir thanks again to you